# Is there a way to turn a data frame off in ArcMap 10.2?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, data-frame

I have an mxd with three data frames. I've written a python script that loops through a list of user-specified coordinates and scales for each data frame before exporting the mxd as a pdf.

Is there a way to "turn off" one of the data frames using python? (e.g. set data frame 1's visibility to False leaving just data frames 2 and 3 visible). The best idea I can come up with is to move data frames off screen when they're not needed and bring them back when they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On/off doesn't appear to be an option with a data frame. Moving the frame off the document would work with `elementPositionX` and `elementPositionY`. Shrinking the frame to zero is an option as well.

Initial code from python shell in ArcMap:

```
>>> mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
>>> df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames (mxd) [0]
>>> height = df.elementHeight
>>> width = df.elementWidth
```

Data frame off:

```
>>> df.elementHeight = 0
>>> df.elementWidth = 0
```

Data frame on:

```
>>> df.elementHeight = height
>>> df.elementWidth = width
```

Comment: Cheers Emil! I thought it might not be possible as I couldn't see anything about it anywhere. I think the data frame size option you mentioned sounds like the best workaround as it would also mean any extent rectangles in other data frames would also disappear.

Comment: Thinking about it, the only issue I see with the shrink method is it may create a single pixel on your map if the data frame has a border. Let us know if it does.

Comment: I'll give it a go over the next few days - will keep you posted. Ta!